# How to find SQL Database entries within a period of time

Tags: mysql, time, between

I want to detect entries which are within time period from another.

As example:

Event 1 already in DB starts at 11:18pm and ends at 1:55am

Event 2 start at 11:20pm ($eventstart) and end at 1:30pm ($eventend)

Now the second entry should be added, and before that happend it should check if within the time another already exist.
In table eventstart and evenend are timestamps.

With this query that one could not detect.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as within_time 
FROM `events` 
WHERE eventstart BETWEEN '$eventstart' and '$eventend' 
OR eventend BETWEEN '$eventstart' and '$eventend'
```

-

Is it possible with a SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your checker is bad.
If I good understood you:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as within_time 
FROM `events` 
WHERE $eventstart BETWEEN eventstart and eventend  
OR $eventend BETWEEN eventstart and eventend
```